# set multiple columns derived from another column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help. No matter what I do I always get some kind of length mismatch error when trying to set multiple columns.

These 2 lines work:

```
df.loc[(condition), ['column1', 'column2']] = 10, 20
df.loc[(condition), ['column1', 'column2']] = df['column3'] + 10
```

This gives error `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

```
df.loc[(condition), ['column1', 'column2']] = df['column3'] + 10, df['column3'] - 10
```

Doesn't make sense to me because `len(column1) = len(column2)`
and `len(df['column3'] + 10) = len(df['column3'] - 10)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at least that are going on

One is -- what is `condition`? if it selects only some rows on the left hand side, there will be a length mismatch

even if the lengths are the same, on the left you have an array of size `(N,2)` (where N is the number of rows) and on the right you have a tuple of two arrays so `(2,N)`. Pandas or numpy does not know how to broadcast them into the same shape

The easiest I think is to go column by column. But the closest I could get to your syntax that works is

```
df.loc[(condition), ['column1', 'column2']] = df[['column3']].values + np.array([10,20])
```

Here numpy broadcast rules kick in on the rhs getting it into the right shape

Comment: thanks I thought pandas would treat them column by column, yes condition returns a subset, but if that was the problem then besides what I'm doing wouldn't `df.loc[(condition), ['column1', 'column2']] = df['column3'] + 10` also give a length mismatch error?

Comment: Hmm I would have thought so but thinking it a bit more, `df['column3'] + 10` is a `pd.Series` so the assignment picks the indices from the lhs and finds them on the rhs and ignores the rest so it works. But when you do`..=a,b` the rhs is not a pandas series or dataframe so the same indexing logic does not apply

Comment: Thanks ya that makes sense, using + np.array([10,20]) did not work, I'm just going to update each column separately.

Comment: Makes sense. You can also try to apply `condition` on the rhs

Comment: I think its cleaner to separate them